# PHP explode function causing issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a twitter style following system for my site. When ever the script below runs is adds an "Array" inside the database instead of just the user id of the person you're trying to follow. Dunno how to fix it.

```
<?
session_start();
# Connect to the mysql database
include_once "library/connect_to_mysql.php"; 

if(isSet($_POST['mem'])){

#filter everything but numbers for security
$mem1 = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['mem']); 
$mem2 = $mem1;

#Decode the Session IDX variable and extract the user's ID from it
$decryptedID = base64_decode($_SESSION['idx']);
$id_array = explode("p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234", $decryptedID);
$my_id = $id_array[1];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT following_array FROM Members WHERE id='$my_id' LIMIT 1"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
$following = $row["following_array"]; 
}

$followArry1 = explode(',', $following);

if (in_array($mem1, $followArry1)) {

exit(); 
}

if ($followArry1 != "") { 

$followArry2 = "$followArry1,$mem2"; 

} else { 

$followArry2 = "$mem2"; 
}

$UpdateArray = mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET following_array ='$followArry2' WHERE id='$my_id'") or die (mysql_error());

exit();

}else{

exit();
}

?>
```

[image: explode (array,2)]

Any help appreciated

```
/////// Updated Code ////////////////////

$followArry1 = explode(",", $following);

if (in_array($mem1, $followArry1)) { exit(); }

if ($followArry1 != "") { 

    $followArry1 = implode(',', $followArry1 + array($mem1)); 

} else { 

    $followArry1 = $mem1; 
}

$UpdateArray = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET following_array ='$followArry1' WHERE id='$my_id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: `print_r($followArry2)` what is the output?

Comment: Why are you comparing an array to a string?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I also think that the problem is with adding $mem variable to $followyArry1 array.

Try this code...

```
if ($followArry1 != "") { 
    $followArry1[] = $mem1;
    $followArry1 = implode(',', $followArry1); 

} else { 

    $followArry1 = $mem1; 
}
```

Comment: @uttam: Could you explain how "_your_" solution differs from mine?

Comment: What a magnificent example of copying other people's answers ;) You did not even put the effort to change the content of example variables ;)

Comment: @zizozu Thanks for the suggestion... so made changes according to the question.

Comment: @Tadeck Your logic and mine was the same just the syntax is different.. just the difference is you tried to explain whole lot of Array to Raphael1 not the answer and i just posted the answer

Comment: @uttam: so basically you copied the essence of my answer, changing one thing (I used sum of two arrays without changing existing variable, you just placed line appending element to existing array). Honestly, still something I would be ashamed. But I am able to forget if the explanation is at least half-correct - right now it states the problem was an addition, in my oppinion it was casting array to string.

Comment: @Tadeck Honestly speaking i just found the bug in the code and used your example to explain it better to Raphael1.

Answer (score 2):

`$followArry1` is an array, which converted to string shows "`Array`".

See proof here (live demo: http://ideone.com/tMndH):

```
$followArry1 = array('a', 'b', 'c'); // just an array
$result = "$followArry1"; // it is now string containing "Array"
```

Try the following (example here: http://ideone.com/h5ilz):

```
$followArry1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$mem = 'd';
$followArry2 = implode(',', $followArry1 + array($mem));
```

Comment: @Raphael1: It does not insert anything into the database, it was meant to show you the problem and point you to solution. Post full code that causes the error. Short tip: you just need to replace `$followArry2 = "$followArry1,$mem2";` line with last line of my solution. This is _extremely_ easy.

Comment: @Raphael1: How does the code behave now? Turn error reporting to the highest level possible and tell me if: 1) it displays anything, 2) you see any notices, 3) it shows you an error.

Comment: @Raphael1: What is your error reporting level? Do you even get any output? How do you know the query is even executed? Do you know what happens when you run the code? Anything?

Comment: The field in my database is set to NULL by default, when the query is run it insert an empty value in the database.

Comment: @Raphael1: "_empty_" in PHP is very wide concept (it may be `0`, `NULL`, `''` etc.). What _exactly_ is entered into your database? `NULL`? Try to print out your query before executing it (using `var_dump()`, not `echo` or `print`) - this is basic method of debugging.